# How do you calculate the length of a planets shadow?

Tags: astronomy

Given the diameter of the sun, the diameter of a planet, and the distance between them, how do you calculate the length of the planets shadow?

Answer (score 2):

By similar triangles.  Call the sun's radius R, the planet's radius r, the sun-planet distance d, and the planet's umbra's length u.

Then the ratio R : d+u is the same as r : u.
Rearrange to isolate u, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Also, https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/shadowfacts.png